# Understanding termination in minikanren counting bits in a list

Tags: logic-programming, minikanren

I began studying some minikanren and made up this example for counting 1-bits in a list.

```
(define (count xs n)
  (conde
   [(== xs '()) (== n 0)]
   [(fresh (a b)
           (== xs (cons a b))
           (conde
            [(== a 0) (count b n)]
            [(== a 1) (count b (- n 1))]))]))
```

Now the following works fine

```
> (run* (q) (fresh (a b c) (== q (list a b c)) (count q 1)))
'((0 0 1) (1 0 0) (0 1 0))
```

but if I change the order of the goals the program does not terminate

```
> (run* (q) (fresh (a b c) (count q 1) (== q (list a b c))))
. . user break
```

This is already something that I don't completely understand, does the order of goals matter? In which ways? I think I understood that even the subsequent goals can pose sufficient constraints so as to terminate the search, but of course I must have missed something.

Exploring more of this problem I saw that

```
> (run 3 (q) (fresh (a b c) (count q 1) (== q (list a b c))))
'((0 0 1) (0 1 0) (1 0 0))
> (run 4 (q) (fresh (a b c) (count q 1) (== q (list a b c))))
. . user break
```

so I know that it tries to look for more answers than existing. My suspect now is that when the subgoal

```
(== xs (cons a b))
```

splits the list there aren't sufficient constraints on `b` to make the search finite, which sounds reasonable given that nothing talks about the tail of the list besides the external `(== q (list a b c))`. It seems even more reasonable to expect a non termination as nothing says what `c` is in `(== q (list a b c))`, it may be another list (is it true?), but so how does the swapped version of the program terminate?

I therefore tried

```
(define (bit x)
  (conde [(== x 0)] [(== x 1)]))
```

and

```
> (run 4 (q) (fresh (a b c) (bit a) (bit b) (bit c) (count q 1) (== q (list a b c))))
. . user break
```

but it still does not terminate, so maybe the problem is not that which I thought.

Overall there must be something that I'm missing in my understanding, can anyone clarify all this and point out what would be a correct way of doing this thing?

Answer (score 0):

```
> (run* (q) (fresh (a b c) (== q (list a b c)) (count q 1)))
'((0 0 1) (1 0 0) (0 1 0))
```

This query terminated because the 1st conjunct `(== q (list a b c))` bound the size of `q` ,i.e. length of `(list a b c)` is 3. So the 2nd conjunct `(count q 1)` can only succeed finitely many times. Thus it terminates.

```
(run* (q) (fresh (a b c) (count q 1) (== q (list a b c))))
. . user break
```

This query diverged because the 1st conjunct `(count q 1)` keeps associating `q` with larger and larger lists without bound. Note that the 2nd conjunct `(== q (list a b c))` can produce three answers, but after that, it will never succeed. Thus whenever it fails, it backtracks into `(count q 1)`, which succeeds again, and fails again, backtracks again, ... and repeats forever (`q` will be larger and larger).

You asked that

> This is already something that I don't completely understand, does the order of goals matter?

The answer is yes.

As William E. Byrd said in his [dissertation](https://search.proquest.com/docview/304903505):

> miniKanren’s conjunction operator (exist) is commutative, but only if an answer exists. If no answer exists, then reordering goals within an exist may result in divergence rather than failure.
>
> We say that conjunction is commutative, modulo divergence versus failure.